# Where does Edge store information about the default homepage?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Where does Edge store information about the default homepage?
in which registry or file?

Comment: If you define a file for your home page and enter that in Settings, it will keep the file where you put it. I do that. If you use a bookmark as home page, it will keep it with your bookmarks.

Comment: No, I have no access to Edge, I want to check the Edge homepage setting through examing registry or files, are the homepage setting maintain in files or registry?

Answer (score 0):

In the registry editor, go to:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\RestoreOnStartupURLs
```

You can read the value with the next Power Shell script

```
$EdgeHome = 'HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge'
$EdgeSUURL = "$EdgeHome\RestoreOnStartupURLs"
Get-ItemProperty -Path $EdgeSUURL -Name '1'
```

You can use this Power Shell script to change it:

```
# Ensure Edge key exists
$EdgeHome = 'HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge'
If ( -Not (Test-Path $EdgeHome)) {
  New-Item -Path $EdgeHome | Out-Null
}
# Set RestoreOnStartup value entry
$IPHT = @{
  Path   = $EdgeHome
  Name   = 'RestoreOnStartup'
  Value  = 4
  Type   = 'DWORD'
}
Set-ItemProperty @IPHT -verbose
# Create Startup URL's registry key
$EdgeSUURL = "$EdgeHome\RestoreOnStartupURLs"
If ( -Not (Test-Path $EdgeSUURL)) {
  New-Item -Path $EdgeSUURL | Out-Null
}
# Create a single URL startup page
$HOMEURL = 'https://duckduckgo.com'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $EdgeSUURL -Name '1' -Value $HomeURL
```

Read more on the original source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/how-to-change-the-start-page-for-the-edge-browser/